# How to make a View object in Java in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In my program I have a class called GameView that is a View meaning it has Context and attrs attached to it. I have several non static methods and variables in this class that I would like to call in my MainActivity class but since it takes context and attrs I cant seem to figure out how to properly create an object in this situation. I have tried creating Context and SetAttribute variables in MainActivity to fill in the missing gaps but I think it makes it have a null exception and the app crashes as a result. I really need help on this since if I get this fixed I think my program will work really well. Below is a simplified version of  my issue.

This is what I tried doing in the MainActivity to create object of GameView and to call the Method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GameView gv = new GameView(context, attrs);
        gv.myMethod();
```

This is what is in the GameView Class:

```
public class GameView extends View {

    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public void MyMethod() {
         //stuff happens here
    }
```

Comment: `View` has a constructor that takes only a `Context`. That is, you don't have to have an `AttributeSet` to instantiate one. That said, we would need to see a [mcve] to give specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

it is okay for me

```
 public class GameView extends View {
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }



    public void MyMethod() {
        //stuff happens here
    }

}
```

in MainActivity in onCreate:

```
AttributeSet attrs = new AttributeSet(){
    @Override
    public int getAttributeCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeName(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeValue(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeValue(String namespace, String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPositionDescription() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeNameResource(int index) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeListValue(String namespace, String attribute, String[] options, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getAttributeBooleanValue(String namespace, String attribute, boolean defaultValue) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeResourceValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeIntValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeUnsignedIntValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public float getAttributeFloatValue(String namespace, String attribute, float defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeListValue(int index, String[] options, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getAttributeBooleanValue(int index, boolean defaultValue) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeResourceValue(int index, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeIntValue(int index, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeUnsignedIntValue(int index, int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public float getAttributeFloatValue(int index, float defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdAttribute() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassAttribute() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIdAttributeResourceValue(int defaultValue) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getStyleAttribute() {
        return 0;
    }
}; 



GameView gv = new GameView(MainActivity.this,attrs);
gv.MyMethod();
```

other way create attrs use below link:

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#java

Comment: How would you make an object and method call of the method that has both context and attrs or is it the same for all three versions?

Comment: Just another thought: If you needed to send attrs what would the code for that be?